# I want to draw some lines by Charts, not line chart, how to do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

Sorry of my poor English.

This is my description of my question.

I want to draw some lines by Charts(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I have the information about line.

For example:

```
@interface Line : NSObject
@property (assign, nonatomic) float x1;//x of the first point
@property (assign, nonatomic) float x2;//x of the second point
@property (assign, nonatomic) float y1;//y of the first point
@property (assign, nonatomic) float y2;//y of the second point

-(instancetype)initWithX1:(float)x1 withY1:(float)y1 withX2:(float)x2 withY2:(float)y2;
@end
```

I put the object of line into the array, then I want to draw it.

How can I achieve this function?

Comment: Try to add transparent view after chart view and implement **drawInRect:** on this view.

Comment: @Sergey Can you provide more information to me? Which class does the method drawInRect: belong to?

Comment: Did you look at the Charts Demo ?

Comment: @Koen I have solved , you can see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find an excellent way to draw the chart.

You can download the Charts Demo from github , then I find the multiple line chart, like this
[Multiple Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06FF4.png)

If I change the color of the line then I can solve the problem. This is my code:

```
    ((LineChartDataSet *)dataSets[0]).colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor clearColor]];
```

I re-run the project, perfect~!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkQeu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Every View has `drawRect:` method.
Simply create new view and override its drawrect method.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

To perform drawing itself you can use UIBezierPath inside:

```
UIBezierPath * axis = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
axis.lineWidth = 1;
[axis moveToPoint: startOfAxis];
[axis addLineToPoint: endOfAxis];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[axis stroke];
```

or use `CGContextFillRect`

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// Colors
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, backgroundColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor.CGColor);

// Drawing
CGContextFillRect(context, textRect);
CGContextStrokeRect(context, textRect);

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```